# How to retrieve the index of HTML collection when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Trying to make a function to get the `index` whenever the `edit icon` is clicked. Even though there's a solutions using `closure`, still not working with my case and getting wrong results, when there's more than one edit icon.

When I have three icons, my console outputs:

1. `(3) 0`
2. `(2) 1`
3. `2`

Need to know why the console is this.

Here's a `js` fiddle with the full code :https://jsfiddle.net/c2L4buj6/5/

Sample code **JS**:

```js
function clickEnable(input, title, url, plus, editIcon, anchorEdit, edit)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < editIcon.length; i++){
      editIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function(i){
        console.log(i);
      }.bind(null, i));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
To show the error more clearly, uploaded a photo on whats going on. In the photo, there are three boxes and when clicked on the edit icon it return the right value, but also returns copies of the right value. I want to know what is causing this.

[Here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqHRH.jpg)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/c2L4buj6/9/ It seems like it return the valid index

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki check the update

Comment: Your `clickEnable` is called on every submit, and adds an event listener to every element inside the `editIcon` variable. So, when you click *submit* for the first time, a click listener is added to editIcon-0, when you click *submit* again, a click listener is added to editIcon-0 again, and one is added editIcon-1. Now, editIcon-0 have two click listeners, hence the multiple alert/console.log ... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not removing the old event listeners, so you get duplicates for all previously-added elements.

One solution ([tested](https://jsfiddle.net/oLk6vz0d/) based on your fiddle):

```
function clickEnable(input, title, url, plus, editIcon, anchorEdit, edit)
{
  let i = editIcon.length - 1;
  editIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

Comment: Won't i be held in the closure and updated each iteration, making each i the same (the last i in the loop)?

Comment: Sorry @WillCain that did not work. Check my update. Also I provided a picture showing the error that I am getting.

Comment: @BryanWong sorry I diagnosed incorrectly before; updated my answer after your explanation